# Integration page in admin panel not show my custom API

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, integration, customapi

Integration page in admin panel not show my custom API in the list, because i need to allow my endpoint for particular integration user not for authenticated user or is there any other way to achieve this. I think when we create a new integration, after using the provided token we can send to particular user to use the endpoint with token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an ACL in your module to control access to API in integrations.

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_Module::name" title="Product List"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/products" method="GET">
    <service class="Venodor\Module\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="getProducts"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Vendor_Module::name"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```